# Enabling shr-external-rendering-functions Variable in EWW

Tags: eww, shr

Began using Emacs `eww` nowadays, but now seeking to adapt it better for Html websites.

That way some user said to "buffer-locally setting the variable `shr-external-rendering-functions`", as of [What EWW Emacs Web Brower Would Be Used For](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/56353/what-eww-emacs-web-brower-would-be-used-for?noredirect=1#comment88373_56353)

But don't know how to do it.

Any idea?

Comment: Improving `eww` is a high aim which requires some experience in Elisp. I said in [the comment to your other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/56353/what-eww-emacs-web-brower-would-be-used-for?noredirect=1#comment88373_56353) that you can adapt `eww` to HTML-like formats with additional tags. That story is a bit different.

Comment: Just adjusted it, @Tobias.

Comment: If nobody other jumps in I'll answer this weekend.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Consider that Emacs has inherent limitations regarding what you can and cannot render. `shr-external-rendering-functions` is nice for things like adding support for unknown tags or adjusting how an existing tag is rendered (for example making all header tags display as large fonts). What you don't get is the level of control as seen from CSS.

Comment: I wrote https://github.com/xuchunyang/shr-tag-pre-highlight.el, it's sole purpose is add syntax highlight to `<pre>`, it's done by adding an item to `shr-external-rendering-functions`, so we can control how shr/eww render `<pre>`. HTML-only or with little inline-CSS webpage should look fine in EWW, don't forget shr/eww can't really understand CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Thought in visualize properly rendered something like #container, #main, #body divisions as we can see in css styling, @wasamasa, instead of without vertical divisions, as current situation here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to generally change/add the rendering of nodes of a certain tag type you just add an association from the tag as symbol to the rendering function in the list `shr-external-rendering-functions`.

Example: Render `<em>` nodes using a self defined function `my-tag-em`:

```el
(add-to-list 'shr-external-rendering-functions '(em . my-tag-em))
```

I have tested the code with Emacs 26.3.
The rendering function recieves the node as parsed by `libxml-parse-html-region` and should insert the rendered representation of the node at point of the current buffer (which is the `eww-mode` buffer).

The structure of the nodes is described in [on the page about the Document Object Model (DOM) in the info manual for Elisp <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(Elisp)Document Object Model")` <kbd>RET</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Document-Object-Model.html).

Each node is a list. The elements are:

- **0th:** tag name as a symbol
- **1st:** association list of attributes, each attribute is represented as a cons:

  - **car:** attribute name as a symbol
  - **cdr:** value as a string
- **rest:** contents of the tag as children of the node

Example: <kbd>M-:</kbd>  `(libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max))` <kbd>RET</kbd> for the following html buffer returns the subsequent DOM.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body style=none>
    Test of <em>emphasis</em>.
  </body>
</html>
```

The corresponding DOM:

```el
(html nil (head nil (title nil "Test")) (body ((style . "none")) "
    Test of " (em nil "emphasis") ".
  "))
```

Next we define our rendering function `my-tag-em` such that it frames the contents of the `<em>` tag by Org-style `*` characters. One can use `shr-generic` to render the contents (i.e., the children) of the tag.

```el
(defun my-tag-em (dom)
  "Render <em>-tag DOM as *CONTENT*."
  (insert "*")
  (shr-generic dom)
  ;; point is now behind the contents
  (insert "*"))
```

Finally, we have a look at `shr-tag-em` which is normally used by `shr` for rendering the `<em>` tag. 
The used function `shr-fontize-dom` is listed with additional comments.

```el
(defun shr-tag-em (dom)
  (shr-fontize-dom dom 'italic))

(defun shr-fontize-dom (dom &rest types)
  (let ((start (point))) ;; remember start of inserted region
    (shr-generic dom) ;; inserts the contents of the tag
    (dolist (type types)
      (shr-add-font start (point) type)) ;; puts text properties of TYPES on the inserted contents
    ))
```